# Rails 4.2.x - use params hash data in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, parameters

**QUESTION** - is there a way to pass/use `params` hash data to the associated model?

Essentials of my app:

1. `Image` model `belongs_to` `User` model, `User` model `has_many` `Image` instances.
2. `Image` schema:

   create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
       t.string   "filename"
       t.string   "mime_type"
       t.binary   "content"
       t.integer  "user_id"
       t.datetime "created_at", null: false
       t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
     end

   add_index "images", ["user_id"], name: "index_images_on_user_id"
3. In root_url (which is `StaticPagesController#home`) I have image upload form:
4. in `Image` model I do:

   ```
   def uploaded_file=(initial_data)
     self.filename = initial_data.original_filename
     self.mime_type = initial_data.content_type
     self.content = initial_data.read
     initial_data.rewind
   end
   ```
5. Also a custom validation:

   ```
   validate :mime_type
   ```

with

```
def mime_type
    correct_mime = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
    unless correct_mime.include? params[:image][:uploaded_file].content_type.chomp
        errors.add(:base, 'must be .jpeg, .png or .gif')
    end
end
```

5. As it is known all query from upload form goes to params[:image][:uploaded_file]

**6. Is it possible to pass params[:image][:uploaded_file] to `Image` model as a hash with original hash structure?**

What I have tried and none of them works:

- pass explicit params hash right in `Image` model - NO GO
- define instance @params_hash = params[:image][:uploaded_file] in `create` action (separately or from inside the custom class method) - NO GO
- Define constant in `controller#action` - NO GO

WHAT works??
Global variable - `$variable`

Is it a rails way to do that? -> query data to model

Comment: Why can't you use `mime_type` instead of `params[:image][:uploaded_file].content_type`?  Unless I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: The minor problem (this case) is how to extract uploaded file content_type from params hash in model, the major problem is - how to use correctly params hash in appropriate model for future apps.

Comment: @japed - could you please present it as an answer with what exactly you are suggesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a good MVC app your models should not be aware of the parameters, the request or any direct user input. The model just takes data from the controller and enforces the business logic and persists the data.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_inclusion_of :mime_type,
      in: ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"],
      message: 'must be .jpeg, .png or .gif'
end
```

---

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  def create
    @image = Image.new(
      filename: image_params.original_filename
      mime_type: image_params.content_type,
      content: image_params.read
    )
    if @image.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def image_params
      params.require(:image).require(:uploaded_image)
    end
end
```

Comment: All answers are great, but I choose to accept max`s explanation, as it is closest to what works for me + short explanation what good MVC app should do in general

Comment: Of course if you are developing a specialized model for attachments it's fully valid for it to take a file object as input and for example extract the content type.

Answer (score 2):

The model code seems to be correct, it's just the way you're attempting to get the image data to the model that is against convention. Usually you would create a new `Image` instance in your controller and then set the image data, like so:

```
image = user.images.new # If "user" is set to the correct user for the image
image.uploaded_file = params[:image][:uploaded_image]
# ...whatever else you need to do with the image here
image.save
```

That's a barebones controller action, so you're going to want to make sure the `Image` validates and handle validation errors and whatnot, but hopefully that will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have

```
def uploaded_file=(initial_data)
  self.filename = initial_data.original_filename
  self.mime_type = initial_data.content_type
  self.content = initial_data.read
  initial_data.rewind
end
```

So you're setting the mime_type to the content_type of the file.

Why can't you do

```
def mime_type
  correct_mime = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
  unless correct_mime.include? mime_type.chomp
    errors.add(:base, 'must be .jpeg, .png or .gif')
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks logically, but what I get is only busy state of browser and:
`...`
`app/models/image.rb:17:in \`mime_type'`
`app/models/image.rb:17:in \`mime_type'`
`app/controllers/images_controller.rb:11:in \`create'`

Comment: and my `ImagesController` line 11 is:
`if @image.save`